# Catching exceptions without a catch block

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I'm working in a legacy project (read: refactoring is not an option) that is throwing `ApplicationException`s.

```
throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("More than one type found with the name {0} in {1}", typeName, assemblies));
```

**Context**

I'm a relatively new dev. *Basic* throwing/catching exceptions explicitly makes sense to me. Even the concept of exceptions bubbling up the call stack to a different catch statement feels intuitive.

Beyond that I know the CLR is capable of.. something. This line is particularly confusing (from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab(v=vs.110).aspx))

> The exception is passed up the stack until the application handles it or the program terminates.

I cannot find a single catch statement in this entire solution, which would leave me to think that the exception would terminate the process, but I'm seeing an error message on the front end instead - process runs on.

The top of my call stack is spinning up a new thread and above that is external code. I would show more code if it weren't proprietary.

```
Dim installThread As New Thread(CType(Sub() InstallPackageAsyncInner(appsToOverride, package, parameters), Threading.ThreadStart))
```

**The Question**

Is it possible that the thread that was spun up died, and the parent thread is what's ultimately propagating an error message and processing the exception?

If so, how does this transfer of control take place in `.NET` or whatever relevant technology handles it?

Comment: I realize I probably just rubber-duck debugged myself, but I'll still post this in case it helps another.

Comment: There are just fragments of information plus irrelevant trivia, while all that's needed is laid out very clearly in the posting guideline, like e.g. a minimal but complete example.

Comment: if you can't find a single exception handler, all that springs to mind is someone has registered for unhandled exceptions at the appdomain level...is there any UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler in the code?

Comment: Either the unhandled exception handler or the exception is thrown in a threadpool thread and we're running .net 4.5.

Comment: Yeah this is a pretty vague question, but things like "registered for unhandled exceptions at the appdomain level" at least gives me something I can google. Thanks @NDJ! I'll close this question as I couldn't get anywhere explicit with what I was asking

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, that's not at all helpful and rather condescending, I read the posting guidlines and did what I could to make it fit (calling out the fact that it's proprietary so I cannot post a full example). But yes, it's clear it's not a perfect match, and yet I still got the information I needed by posting it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Have a good one. I'll close the topic as mis-worded or whatever.

Comment: You can't post a full example? How about the minimal example without which your question is considered off-topic? Just strip everything that's not necessary to demonstrate the issue. Actually, doing so is a tool to analyze the issue that every programmer should know about, because it helps you solve problems in and of itself! That's also the reason it's required, because it prevents stupid questions. But hey, I'm getting called condescending because I tell you that you ignore rules, conventions and good advise.

Comment: I'm unaware how to create a "simple example" because I don't know what's causing the behavior I'm seeing. How would you suggest circumventing that? My call stack was roughly 15 methods deep. Implying that my question is stupid is precisely why you come across as rather condescending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're throwing exceptions on the UI, the the call stack has a try-catch frame on it from `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback`, which is usually the root of the UI thread:

```
    private IntPtr Callback(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) {

        // Note: if you change this code be sure to change the 
        // corresponding code in DebuggableCallback below!

        Message m = Message.Create(hWnd, msg, wparam, lparam);

        try {
            if (weakThisPtr.IsAlive && weakThisPtr.Target != null) {
                WndProc(ref m);
            }
            else {
                DefWndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            OnThreadException(e);
        }
        finally {
            if (msg == NativeMethods.WM_NCDESTROY) ReleaseHandle(false);
            if (msg == NativeMethods.WM_UIUNSUBCLASS) ReleaseHandle(true);
        }

        return m.Result;
    }
```

From there, it invokes the `Application.ThreadException` handler. A default handler is installed that informs you of the exception. After that, the exception is usually swallowed and your UI is given the chance to continue running.

Answer (score 0):

The exception handling must be happening at the AppDomain level (as I am running .NET 4.5.1).

Ultimately the `AppDomain` is what manages the various threads and handles the flow of control in this scenario.